# How to fix ionic icons?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Whenever I build my app I get the warning:

```
icon android drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png (192x192) skipped, source image icon.png (144x144) too small
icon wp8 Background.png (159x159) skipped, source image icon.png (144x144) too small
icon ios icon-60@3x.png (180x180) skipped, source image icon.png (144x144) too small
icon ios icon-76@2x.png (152x152) skipped, source image icon.png (144x144) too small
```

Why is this so and how to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided image icon.png is too small.

The icon image’s minimum dimensions should be 192x192 px.

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

Comment: `ionic resources --icon` for the icon, and `ionic resources --splash` for the splash icon. Follow the link in my answer, it should be very simple.